# JavaScript Syntax for creating DOM nodes as variables

Tags: javascript, html, dom, nodes

Firstly, I'm trying to create multiple DOM nodes and cache them as a variable for use in a function. What I want to do is create a function that sets-up the elements by classname. Then call that function as variable for use later.

Secondly, I'm not sure what the correct syntax is when manipulating inserted nodes via classname, when you want to select all classes with that name.

i.e `for (var i = 0; i < insertedNodes.length; i++) {`

To clarify what exactly I'm asking, my questions are this:

1. How to insert nodes as variables for use later on in function.
2. How to call those each of those variables.
3. How to call both of those variables together.

Hopefully my code will help explain what I'm trying to understand a little further:

```
var div1 = document.querySelector('.div1');
var div2 = document.querySelector('.div2');

var node1     = {};
var node2     = {};
var bothNodes = {};


function nodes() {

   function insertNodes() { 
     node1 = div1.appendChild(nodeBase);
     node2 = div2.appendChild(nodeBase);
     bothNodes = [node1, node2];
   }

   function nodeBase() {
     var node = document.createElement('div');
     node.className = 'newNode';
   }

   function dosomething(node1, node2) {
   //

   }

    function dosomethingElse(bothNodes) {
   //

   }

}

new nodes();
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what exactly you are asking for.

Comment: How to insert nodes and store them as variables for use in a function

Comment: `.appendChild` and `.insertBefore` insert DOM nodes. And you store elements in variable by just assigning them to variables, e.g. `var foo = element;`. And you seem to be doing that already. *edit:* ah, you are not calling and returning from `nodeBase`. Learn more about functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions.

Comment: Aren't you storing it currently in `bothNodes`? please explain what is not working, are you getting error messages..? check you're console.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out using the DOM's API or re-implementing/abstracting it? A `Node` type [already exists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) and its instances can certainly be stored in variables.

Comment: The literal answer for the title of your question would be `var element = document.createElement('div');`, which you already seem to be doing. That's why it's not clear what your problem is.

Comment: To your point here: "Secondly, I'm not sure what the correct syntax is when manipulating inserted nodes via classname, when you want to select all classes with that name."  I believe you're looking for: document.getElementsByClassName(names);

Comment: i'm updating the question so it's clearer. 1 sec

Comment: Wondering whether answers helped...

Answer (score 0):

You don't return node here..

```
function nodeBase() {
  var node = document.createElement('div');
  node.className = 'newNode';
  // ADD THIS LINE
  return node;
}
```

And, as pointed out by Felix in the comment:

```
function insertNodes() { 
   node1 = div1.appendChild(nodeBase());  // Fixed
   node2 = div2.appendChild(nodeBase());  // Fixed
   bothNodes = [node1, node2];
}
```

Comment: He also has to actually call the function: `div1.appendChild(nodeBase());`

Answer (score 0):

This might get drowned with down votes, but pointing you to another direction.

- <s>How to insert nodes as variables for use later on in function.</s>

you don't actually have to store those elements. You can always query them later.

- How to call  each of those variables.

You can select the first matching element with a particular class as follows:

```
    var div1 = document.getElementsByClassName('.div1')[0];
```

OR

```
    var div1 = document.querySelector('.div1');
```

- How to call both of those variables together.

You can select all elements with a particular class, iterate over the collection and apply your logic as follows:

```
    var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('.div1');
```

OR

```
    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.div1');

    for(var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){
       // your loic
    }
```